# Getting metacarta to work with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have an issue with getting QGIS to accept the metacarta WMS service.

Can anyone can guide me?

I add the "basic layers" to the map, but still can't see the tiles there when I go to the map. I even do the right click -> `zoom to layer extent`, but there is no visual data in QGIS. Only complete white.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the '+' in front of all entries. You can open them. Double click on the ("leaf") entries that will appear.

Edit: Also, tick both 'Ignore ...' checkboxes.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have also tried this, but just can't get it working. The screen is still blank after adding the maps. Could it be the zoom level? It should be enough to right click and choose Zoom to layer extent? Thank you!

Comment: If you start with an empty project, the map extents/zoom levels are adjusted automatically. I added a screenshot showing the options I used.

Comment: The two ignore checkboxes did the trick for me. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The *basic* layer contains multiple sublayers.  You have to add one layer at a time.  Expand the tree all the way until there's no + sign.  For example **basic > ground_01 > *default***.  If you get a warning about the GetMap URL not matching the advertised URL, click 'No'.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the MetaCarta service has moved to http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms following Nokia buying/selling MetaCarta.

However when I try (http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms?request=getcapabilities) in QGis 1.6 I get the following error:

> msLoadMap(): Unable to access file. (/osgeo/tiles/vmap0/.map)

so something is clearly up at present.

Comment: That's not the URL for the WMS. It's http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0. Presumably he's past that though, because he is getting the capabilities, but maybe qgis handles that redirect, but won't handle a redirect for the tiles.

Comment: My bad - but I think I copied that url out of the capablities file that I got from QGIS.

Comment: Looking at http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS does lead to the getMap and getCapabilties links of http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms? so I think you need to fix something.

Comment: @christopher - I agree with @iant the online resources URL points to  http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms? in the GetCapabilities file, and so all dynamic WMS loading code fails

Comment: The GetCapabilities document for the VMap0 map has never been maintained correctly, and I don't have any real intention of starting now.